# General correlation between function with itself and other input data

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, machine-learning, correlation

- I've collected data for a function `F = f(g(x))`, for different function shapes `g(x)`.
- The goal is to predict values of `F` for general case, i.e. for arbitrary `g(x)`.
- It's know that function derivative `dF/dx` depends on history of development of `dF/dx` and `g(x)` (and maybe `dg/dx`); this connection is something I would like to inspect based on the collected data

In this case, which are possible techniques for finding correlations, i.e. connectivity between `dF/dx` and other variables?